# Pushing Key-Value Pairs into a Hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to push keys and values into a hash as I iterate through some params passed into my controller. The snipper of code below creates an array of hashes, but I want hashes with multiple key value pairs. How do I do this?

```
 @diff_attr = []
 params[place_type].each_pair do |k, v|
   @diff_attr << {k.to_sym=>v}
 end
```

I should change my @diff_attr to be a hash: `@diff_attr = { }`, but after this, I'm not sure how to pass the key and value inside my iterating block.

Currently, if I `puts @diff_attr`, I get something like:

`{:name => "blah blah"}, {:age => "24"}`

but I want something more like:

`{:name=>"blah blah", :age=>"24"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @diff_attr = {}
 params[place_type].each_pair do |k, v|
   @diff_attr[k.to_sym] = v
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid now. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@diff_attr = params[place_type].each_with_object({}) do |k,v,hash|
  hash[k.to_sym] = v
end
```